# Is there any similar function like utf8-encode(php) in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Is there any similar function like **utf8-encode**(php) in javascript?

If not what is the most optimized way to achieve utf8 encoding in javascript?

I followed the following link but it has its own disadvantage.
http://ecmanaut.blogspot.ca/2006/07/encoding-decoding-utf8-in-javascript.html

Comment: Can you elaborate on the disadvantages of the solution you link to?

Comment: The answer to the question you actually *asked* is "no, there's nothing like that built into JavaScript." But it sounds like you're really asking for a suggested library or something to do it.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi from one of the comment i read in the above link Just a heads up: this approach doesn’t work for unmatched surrogate halves, since the `URI` functions throw errors on those. It works fine for all Unicode symbols except high surrogates (code points 0xD800 to 0xDBFF) and low surrogates (code points 0xDC00 to 0xDFFF).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yeah right ,i just want to know how to do that in javascript.

Comment: [This](http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-utf8.html#.Uq7Z7_TuLzM) looks like it suits your needs.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript itself does not have this.
But there is another implementation at [php.js/functions/utf8_encode](http://phpjs.org/functions/utf8_encode/)
Maybe it helps.

Comment: thanks for replying,i will try this and will keep you updated but i am looking for a simpler approach.

Comment: This version is wrong and not support Georgian language and Tailand.
Use as example this http://phpjs.org/functions/utf8_encode/

Diff in "} else if (c1 & 0xF800 != 0xD800) {"

Comment: I removed the code, it was copied from an older version of that function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a library to do that : https://code.google.com/p/stringencoding/